# How to get edm data types(odata types) of any crm entity attributes

Tags: dynamics-crm, olingo

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0//EntityDefinitions(LogicalName=account)/Attributes?$select=LogicalName,AttributeType,AttributeOf
```

This api gives me data types as Picklist,Money etc (crm data types), what i'm looking for is edm data types like Edm.Int32(picklist),Edm.Decimal(Money)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the metadata lacks any reference to the native .NET types.

[This table](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/dynamicscrm/docs/DataTypeMapping.html) provides the mapping.

Here's a screenshot too:
[image: type mapping]

Here's one way that I've mapped them in code:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<AttributeTypeCode, Type>
{
    {AttributeTypeCode.Integer, typeof(int) },
    {AttributeTypeCode.BigInt, typeof(long) },
    {AttributeTypeCode.Decimal, typeof(decimal) },
    {AttributeTypeCode.Double, typeof(double) },
    {AttributeTypeCode.DateTime, typeof(DateTime) },
    {AttributeTypeCode.Money, typeof(decimal) },
};
```